# Display nested JSON items in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

SOLVED:

This is my first effort to try out REST with AngularJS to display the location of the user and some required data (nested items) from the JSON data.

I am hitting this URL: http://muslimsalat.com/daily.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

I need to show the below data in a list way which is a nested item:

```
"items":[
        {
            "date_for": "2014-5-5",
            "fajr": "4: 10am",
            "shurooq": "5: 36am",
            "dhuhr": "12: 15pm",
            "asr": "3: 43pm",
            "maghrib": "6: 55pm",
            "isha": "8: 25pm"
        }]
```

and also the below information to show the location.

```
{
    "city": "XX",
    "country": "XX",
}
```

AngularJS:

```
var App = angular.module('MyRESTApp',[]);
App.controller("myRestCntrl",function  ($scope, $http) {
var locationURL = "http://muslimsalat.com/daily.json" + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.jsonp(locationURL).
success(function(data)
{
 $scope.myLocation = data;
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyRESTApp">
<div ng-controller="myRestCntrl">
//ng-repeat here for items
<ul>
<li>Date:{{}}</li>
<li>Fajr:{{}}</li>
//more li
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Please let me know how can I loop through nested items and location for the above JSON [URL](http://muslimsalat.com/daily.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK).

Comment: Can you show us your json data, since the link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for ng-repeat. Please read and follow the examples on:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

If you're still having trouble, please set up a plunker so we'll see what's wrong.

Comment: I want to know in html how to reach the nested "items" element using ng-repeat. Ex: item in myLocation[0]

Comment: I see you solved it, great! :). Sorry for not giving you away the answer, it's just that the docs are really informative and I believe that for basic questions which are on the first pages in each angular tutorial, we should strive for some self learning in order to be better programmers.

Comment: I agree with you @haimlit , Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="namazTimesCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="item in myLocation.items">
<li>
Date - {{item.date_for}}
</li>
<li>    
Fajr - {{item.fajr}} 
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```